# How to scroll like a normal windows when I am using screen

Tags: 12.04

When I use screen, how can I scroll the content of my shell as if i open a normal terminal?

When I do that now, I can only scroll 1 screen of content?

Comment: As an addition to my answer, there is a program caller **gnu screen**. It is capable of this thing you wan't and other stuff but I could never set it up. Maybe you can do it. [Here is a link to project page](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about `tty`'s, you can use `Shift + PageUp` and `Shift + PageDown` buttons.